# Student Marks Hash

Tags: ruby, hash, iteration, each

I've seen solutions posted in other languages but not Ruby so I'm asking here.

I'm trying to create a student marks system using Ruby, this should take the student’s name and two marks from the user for that particular student.

I decided to try and store these in a hash so it would end up looking something like:

```
    student_marks = {
        "Steve" => 45, 65,
        "James" => 20, 75,
        "Scott" => 30, 90
    }
```

My code attempt is as follows:

```
    continue = "y"

    student_grades = Hash.new

    while continue == "y"

    puts "Please enter student name"
    name = gets.chomp

    puts "Please enter the first grade for #{name}"
    grade_one = gets.chomp.to_i

    puts "Please enter the second grade for #{name}"
    grade_two = gets.chomp.to_i


        student_grades.each do |key, value|
            student_grades[key] = name
            student_grades[value] = grade_one
            student_grades[value][1] = grade_two

         end

        puts "Do you want to continue? y or n"
        continue = gets.chomp

    end


    puts student_grades
```

Obviously there is a problem with my logic in trying to populate the hash using each/iteration because I keep getting nil return. I guess I could use arrays and populate the hash from them, but is there a way to populate the hash both the keys and values using iteration from user input?

Comment: Your expected result is invalid in the first place.

Comment: In your code, you start with `student_grades` as an empty hash, then iterate over it, which means you are not doing anything to it.

Comment: Oops thanks! It seems I've got my logic around hashes completely wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be misunderstanding how hashes work in Ruby. I would suggest reading up on it a bit.

In the meantime, try this:

```
student_grades = Hash.new {|h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

Now every time you get a student grade, you can push it into the array value for that student's hash key.

For example:

```
student_grades
=> {}

student_grades['Mark'] << 95
student_grades['Mark'] << 86

student_grades
=> {'Mark' => [95, 86]}
```

You don't need to iterate over the hash at all in each run of your loop, you should only be doing that if you need to extract some information from it.

Comment: Thanks for the advice, your answer is clear. Looks like I have got my logic around hashes wrong, back to the books.

Comment: The part that trips some people up in Ruby is that when instantiating a new hash, if you want Ruby to assume an initial value for each key, you have to be specific about that value. If you just want to set a grade for example, like `grades['Mark'] = 95` this is no problem, however if you want to make a counter like `counts['thing'] += 1`, Ruby does NOT assume that the starting value is `0` - therefor you have to instantiate your hash as `Hash.new(0)` so Ruby knows what you want to start with. The same is true here, we tell Ruby that each new key should start with a new Array object as a value.